# Render AJAX loaded embed video on WP

Tags: ajax, wordpress, video, embed

How can I render embed video (using just simple URL in editor: https://codex.wordpress.org/Embeds) after it was added to DOM via AJAX in WP 4.2.2?
I generate post content with this code:

```
query_posts(array(
    'p' => $post_id
));
while (have_posts()) {
    the_post();
    ...
}
```

Is there any JS function for this? I find this issue on videos stored on Instagram.

Thanks